# jquery scrolling issue, element doesnt stay in position?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jquery snippet which makes an element stay visible on top when scrolling down:

```
            var $window = $(window),
            $stickyEl = $('.rightcol'),
            elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
            $window.scroll(function() {
              var windowTop = $window.scrollTop();
              $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', windowTop > elTop);

        });
```

The CSS:

```
.rightcol.sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
```

when i scroll the right column does stay on top, but it moves to the left, it should be in the right, where the element should be positioned in the first place before scroll or onpage load.
how can i fix this problem.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?  And why do you need JS at all if your position is set to 'fixed'  (this is why we need a fiddle)?

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cY2NW/ @zachary

Comment: html is included in the jsfiddle @milind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have set the scrolling element to `float: right` AND set it to `position: fixed`, which will contradict the float.

When you set an element's `float` property, you are telling the rest of the document to fit other content around that element.

When you set an element's `position` property to `fixed`, or `absolute` you remove it from the normal flow of the document. This means that the space consumed by the element will no longer be accounted for, i.e. it will not effect other elements. This means that if you attempt to set float in addition to fixed positioning, the rest of the document will not flow around the element, as the element's space will not be considered.

Have a look at these:

- [Making Fixed floating element scrolling smoothly in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984580/making-fixed-floating-element-scrolling-smoothly-in-firefox-and-chrome)
- [fixed/floating div element when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735002/fixed-floating-div-element-when-scrolling)

Comment: give me a moment or two to play with your fiddle and see if I can help you further, but the above is the answer to your issue

Comment: If this answer solved your issue or if it helped you to find the answer, please upvote and/or accept